# Which Statistical Test: comparing two samples with speed data

Tags: statistical-significance, t-test, wilcoxon-mann-whitney-test

I have two samples containing drivers' speeds collected before and after a speed limit signal has been put along the street. I want to test whether the two populations differ. There are not the same drivers in the two groups which makes them independent.

Here my questions: which statistical test should I use and why? (t-test, wilcoxson, etc..) does it matter that the speed of consecutive cars is somehow dependent on the car which comes first?

Thank you very much!

Comment: how many measures do you have in each group? Can you at least some ideas how your data is distributed?

Comment: around 1200 in the first and 1400 in the second. One is somehow normally distributed the other one is not. (Ususally they are not normally distributed)

Comment: meh, having so many samples you can just use t-test =) even for up-to-certain-extent crazy distribution it is a lot of dots.

Comment: Although the two samples might be independent *of each other,* you are wise to refer to the likely dependence of speeds *within each sample.*  Have you collected information that might permit the degree of dependence to be quantified?

Comment: What other info do you have? E.g. the time of each measurement might be a clue to traffic levels.